# Summation limit

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \{(1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^4)\cdots(1+x^{2^n})\}= f(x) \text{ for } |x|<1, \text{ then } f(\frac 12)= \text{?}$$

I need a hint to solve this problem because I am unable to proceed in any way with it.

I took logarithm on both sides of $f(x)$ equation and then tried but that didn't help too. I can see that gradually $x\to 0$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Multiply and divide the expression by $1-x$

And use $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$

**EDIT:**
Multiplication and division gives

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{(1-x)(1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^4)\cdots(1+x^{2^n})}{1-x}= f(x)$$

$$=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(1-x^2)(1+x^2)(1+x^4)....(1+x^{2^n})}{1-x}$$Again use $$a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$$
which gives

$$=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(1-x^4)(1+x^4)....(1+x^{2^n})}{1-x}$$
Continuing like this gives

$$f(x)=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1-x^{2^{n+1}}}{1-x}$$

Now what can you conclude if the number $|x|<1$ is raised to an infinitely big power..

Comment: Having done that, I dont see any obvious pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $(1+x)(1+x^2)=1+x+x^2+x^3$. What do you get from multiplying out the first *three* factors?